# Building Rascal from source

Tags: rascal

I'm thinking it might be easiest if I modify the Java syntax used in Rascal to better fit our Java-like language.

Is there a way I can build Rascal from the source? I've cloned the repo from Github and imported it as a project into Eclipse but there are some compilation errors regarding `org.eclipse.imp`. Before I head down the rabbit-hole of trying to get this all to work in Eclipse I thought I would post here to see if there is an easy way to handle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you could build Rascal from scratch; following the developer instructions at https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/wiki/Rascal-Developers-Setup---Step-by-Step

On the other hand, if you wish to simply adapt the Java syntax definition it would be better to clone it into your own files. Grammars may look modular, but in reality there are complex interactions between different parts of the grammar. Better to clone and manage the whole thing as your own than depend on two co-evolving definitions.

If you clone the Java grammar Rascal will generate new parsers for you on-the-fly. If this generation becomes cumbersome, a "cached parser" can help you to optimize the deployment of your tools. Please contact us if you need help with that.